# !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess convert to JSON or other formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

When I query via the rails console to get the data of an invoice. It returns a !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess text. See example below.

> "--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \nformat: xml\ninvoice:
>   !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \n  reference: 5-00000003R\n 
>   invoice_lines: \n  - !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \n    price:
>   \"2.50\"\n    product_id: \"177698\"\n    quantity: \"-1.00\"\n
>   discount_text: 10%\n    retail_price: \"25.00\"\n    subtotal:
>   \"-2.50\"\n  payments: \n  - !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \n
>   payment_type_id: \"6\"\n    amount: \"-20.09\"\n    tender:
>   \"-20.09\"\n  invoice_date: \"2015-06-04T05:56:44Z\"\n  remark:
>   CANCELLED ORDER\n  customer_id: \"182029\"\n  tax_inclusive:
>   \"true\"\n  invoice_tax_rates: \n  - !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \n
>   rate: \"0.12\"\n    amount: \"0.27\"\naction: create\ncontroller:
>   api_invoices\n"

What I need is to get all the product ids in the invoice lines attribute of the invoice. How do I parse this text?

Comment: How and Why are you querying to get the data of an invoice which is giving `HashWithIndifferentAccess` object as a string?

Comment: How are you querying invoices from console? Please add code